# How to create POJO class from a CDA schema without changing the xds file?

Tags: java, xsd, maven-jaxb2-plugin, cda

I have a large CDA schema file which is used in generation of a CDA xml document. I want to generate POJO classes using the xds schema during compiling of code.
I am trying to do this with jaxb2-maven-plugin as below:

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaDirectory>myDirectoryName</schemaDirectory>
                    <schemaFiles>myxsdFile</schemaFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

This seems to work with simple xsd files. But with my CDA it throws error

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.6:xjc
> .
> .
> trying to create the same field twice: id

The part in xsd which is creating problem, due to id being present both as element as well as attribute..is as below:

```
<xs:complexType name="POCD_MT000040.ObservationMedia">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="realmCode" type="CS" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="typeId" type="POCD_MT000040.InfrastructureRoot.typeId" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="templateId" type="II" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="id" type="II" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="languageCode" type="CS" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="value" type="ED" />
            <xs:element name="subject" type="POCD_MT000040.Subject" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="specimen" type="POCD_MT000040.Specimen" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="performer" type="POCD_MT000040.Performer2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="author" type="POCD_MT000040.Author" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="informant" type="POCD_MT000040.Informant12" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="participant" type="POCD_MT000040.Participant2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="entryRelationship" type="POCD_MT000040.EntryRelationship" minOccurs="0"
                maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="reference" type="POCD_MT000040.Reference" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="precondition" type="POCD_MT000040.Precondition" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:ID" />
        <xs:attribute name="nullFlavor" type="NullFlavor" use="optional" />
        <xs:attribute name="classCode" type="ActClassObservation" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="moodCode" type="ActMood" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
```

The solutions for this, so far I could find,
(http://metro.1045641.n5.nabble.com/troubleshoot-quot-trying-to-create-the-same-field-twice-quot-error-td1059643.html) suggest making changes to the xds which is not an option for me. Is there a way other than changing xds or using some other utility?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure your requirements but CDA schema from HL7 is not usable as part of typical XML/java technologies - Additionally the ability to serialize CDA that is conforms to spec such as Consol  is not trivial

i would suggest using MDHT api which support Consol

https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/modeling.mdht

https://github.com/mdht/mdht-models

Comment: just reread your question - short answer is you can not - everyone has to modify the XSD because of the way it was designed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So when you say "everyone has to modify the XSD because of the way it was designed" Do you mean the XSD is flawed? Or you mean by design we are made to modify it?